# Unifying len and S len would lead to infinite value

Tags: type-inference, dependent-type, idris

I am trying to make a function `hpure` that generates an hvect by repeating the same element until it reaches the required length. Each element may have a different type. Ex: If the argument was show each element would be a specialization of the show function.

```
hpure show : HVect [Int -> String, String -> String, SomeRandomShowableType ->  String]
```

This is my attempt:

```
hpure : {outs : Vect k Type} -> ({a : _} -> {auto p : Elem a outs} -> a) -> HVect outs
hpure {outs = []} _ = []
hpure {outs = _ :: _ } v = v :: hpure v
```

This error occurs on the final v:

```
When checking an application of Main.hpure:
        Unifying len and S len would lead to infinite value
```

Why does the error occur and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the type of `v` depends on `outs`, and the recursive call to `hpure` passes the tail of `outs`. So `v` needs to be adjusted as well.

The error is essentially saying that the lengths of `outs` and its tail would have to be the same in order for your version to typecheck.

Here is a version that typechecks.

```
hpure : {outs : Vect k Type} -> ({a : Type} -> {auto p : Elem a outs} -> a) -> HVect outs
hpure {outs = []} _ = []
hpure {outs = _ :: _} v = v Here :: hpure (\p => v (There p))
```